# Add swagger to phoenix framework application

Tags: swagger, phoenix-framework

I am new to Elixir/Phoenix. Is there a way to add Swagger documentation to the Phoenix api project?

I looked at https://github.com/xerions/phoenix_swagger but that was updated several months ago and has unresolved old open issues.

This is another one https://github.com/OpenAperture/swaggerdoc with similar issues.

Or should I be using Maru for api projects?

Answer (score 1):

Both projects get updates. [SwaggerDoc](https://github.com/msawka/swaggerdoc) offers Ecto support, but the Build status has been failing for two months.

[PhoenixSwagger](https://github.com/xerions/phoenix_swagger) doesn't, but depends on extending the controller (which you can use to implement Ecto support yourself). Also it appears to be actively maintained at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

We are actively maintaining https://github.com/everydayhero/phoenix_swagger with additional features

```
defmodule MyApp.UserController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  import PhoenixSwagger

  swagger_path :index do
    get "/users"
    summary "Get users"
    description "Get all users"
    response 200, "Success", :Users
    tag "users"
  end
```